# Paypal "Advanced Checkout" v2/Checkout/Orders json structure

Tags: c#, paypal

I am trying to create a class that I can serialize in c# and cannot seem to get the right structure. Can someone please give me an example of how I would replace the [paymentSource] with a string (eg: "paypal", "card") string variable in a class? The variable itself gets passed in to the controller via the js front end selection via the body.

Documentation Ref:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate/

```
    {
      intent: "CAPTURE",
      purchase_units: [
        {
          amount: {
            currency_code: "USD",
            value: purchaseAmount
          },
        },
      ],
      payment_source: {
        [paymentSource]: {}
      }
    }),
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which button the user clicked. In the example JS code, `[paymentSource]` resolves to the value of that string. So for example the resulting JSON could be:

```
      "payment_source": {
        "paypal": {}
      }
```

That is one case; for others it would be something else.

Comment: Yes, I understand that in your example the "paypal" will change dynamically when the user selects say "card" or something else through PayPal's iframesque bs. The issue I'm having is creating the way to handle that on the backend via string building and or also just creating a class and serializing it then sending it to their endpoint. The problem with this is that they are phasing out PayPal pro and we now get this monstrosity to deal with in the future for integrations from what support says. Fun right...

Comment: I also tried to do this with string building however I keep getting a bad request even though the structure is exact to the documentation as it gets passed. So would really like to be able to do this through a class or some kind of dynamic so that I can just serialize and send.

Comment: What is your resulting string? Log the raw request and response

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue to the problem. For some reason in when you are using httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(url, [this])... [this] absolutely needs to be a object not a json string already in the correct format. When you pass in a string value it must double serialize it or something. Even though when I got the response back from paypal the string content they sent back that represents what I sent was the correct json format but was still giving me a bad request code. Thanks for the quick responses and appreciate all the help. It got me thinking that something was happening how c# was sending it vs postman so it really helped. Thanks again